# Different number of arguments in the return statement with event -

Tags: solidity, return

Here is my code, `dailyquotes` event has 2 arguments and so does return statement, then why the error?

```
pragma solidity >0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: open

contract Letscode{
    struct dailyquote{
        string today;
        uint luckynumber;
    }

    event dailyquotes(uint luckynumber, string today);

    function listinfo() public returns(uint256, string memory) {
        emit dailyquotes(7 , 'love in the air');
        return dailyquotes;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's complaining that you are trying to return something in the function but the function signature doesn't have `returns (<return type>)` defined.

Also, you can't return and event.

if you remove the line

`return dailyquotes;`

the error will go away